# What's the best way to retrieve the module path from the project in python?

Tags: python

```
| foo
|   main.py
|---- one
|    | __init__.py
|------ two
|      | __init__.py
```

Consider the `__init__.py` file situated in the `foo/one/two/__init__.py`.
In this file, I want to print the module PATH :

```
foo/one/two/
```

What the best way to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each module will have a `__name__` attribute, which will give you the dot syntax attribute name of the module.  e.g.:

```
from one import two
print two.__name__
```

This should yield:

```
one.two
```

You could then simply replace the dots with the relevant file separater:

```
import os.path
from one import two
print two.__name__.replace('.', os.path.sep)
```

This will print (on Linux/Unix etc):

```
one/two
```

Or on Windows:

```
one\two
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from foo.one import two
print two.__file__
```

Comment: ImportError: No module named foo.one